# IOError: cannot identify image file for app engine on prod but not localhost

Tags: python, google-app-engine, python-imaging-library

I receive `IOError: cannot identify image` for the code given below for when I deploy app engine but it works perfectly for localhost.

I creates first image but fails the second one on production but success both on localhost

In my app.yaml:

```
libraries:
- name: PIL
  version: "1.1.7"
```

I tried also with

```
libraries:
- name: PIL
  version: latest
```

The relevant code:

```
class UploadFile(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def post(self):
        data = self.request.body
        values = self.request.POST.itervalues()
        files = [v for v in values if isinstance(v, cgi.FieldStorage)]
        img_data = data        
        dataBytesIO = io.BytesIO(img_data) #log label "toto" 
        my_img = Image.open(files[0].file)
        my_img.thumbnail((500, 500), Image.ANTIALIAS)
        thumb_io = BytesIO()
        my_img.save(thumb_io, my_img.format)
        thumbnail_filename_input = create_file(self, thumb_io.getvalue(), "room_picture_thumbnail_" + "somename", files[0].type)
        size = 1000, 1000  #log label  "titi"
        my_img_big = Image.open(files[0].file)  #!!! Fails on production but works on localhost
        width, height = my_img_big.size
        if width > 1000 or height > 1000:
            my_img_big.thumbnail(size,Image.ANTIALIAS)        
        thumb_io2 = BytesIO()
        my_img_big.save(thumb_io2, my_img_big.format)
        filename_input = create_file(self, thumb_io2.getvalue(), "room_picture_" +"somename", files[0].type)
```

gives error below:

```
my_img_big = Image.open(files[0].file)
File "/base/alloc/tmpfs/dynamic_runtimes/python27g/b3d733487011db10/python27/python27_lib/versions/third_party/PIL-1.1.7/PIL/Image.py", line 1980, in open
raise IOError("cannot identify image file")
IOError: cannot identify image file
```

And log snap shot at app engine stackdriver debug:

```
files
[0]
fp
<type '_io.BytesIO'>
disposition_options
file
<type 'cStringIO.StringO'>
innerboundary
''
done
1
disposition
'form-data'
qs_on_post
None
strict_parsing
0
outerboundary
'----WebKitFormBoundarykEX5mAPk1xmDW6B3' # only this line differs between two -> '----WebKitFormBoundaryZxbkkzZRFdunz9Fr' at log labels "toto" and "titi"

name
u'aa.png'
_FieldStorage__file
None
list
None
filename
u'/frpy/uploadFile'
keep_blank_values
True
headers
length
-1
type_options
type
'image/png'
```

I even tried to below code on app engine prod from local with

```
remote_api_stub.ConfigureRemoteApiForOAuth(
        '{}.appspot.com'.format(project_id),
        '/_ah/remote_api')
```

and code:

```
import urllib2 as urllib
import io

fd = urllib.urlopen("https://i.stack.imgur.com/mVt7n.jpg?s=328&g=1")
image_file = io.BytesIO(fd.read())

im = Image.open(image_file)    
im.thumbnail((500, 500), Image.ANTIALIAS)
thumb_io = BytesIO()
im.save(thumb_io, im.format)

size = 1000, 1000
my_img_big = Image.open(image_file)
width, height = my_img_big.size
if width > 1000 or height > 1000:
    my_img_big.thumbnail(size,Image.ANTIALIAS)

thumb_io2 = BytesIO()
my_img_big.save(thumb_io2, my_img_big.format)
```

operating twice on `image_file` works goood.

What could be issue works on localhost but fails on prod?

Tip: my_img.close() works on localhost but not on prod, note also when I do to figure out `files[0].file.close()` on localhost it gives me `ValueError: I/O operation on closed file` so the issue is not related being closed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
files[0].file.seek(0)
```

is the answer, I should rewind it :)